# How do you crop a UIImage correctly

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImage that has a landscape orientation and I want to chop off the edges to make it portrait while maintaining the aspect ratio.

```
  UIImage *photo = myUIImage;

  // width = 3264
  float width = photo.size.width;

  // height = 2448
  float height = photo.size.height;
```

I need to get it too the following size while chopping off the left and right edges (maintaining the center):

```
  width = 1836
  height = 2448
```

Comment: do you want to crop the image itself or is it sufficient to crop the image when it is contained in an imageView ?

Answer (score 0):

idk if it helps but here are the correct dimensions for iPod, iPad, iPhone

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    // iPhone, iPod Touch
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.jpg"];
}

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    // iPhone 5
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.jpg"];
}

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024)
{
    // iPad
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11@2x.jpg"];
}

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:Image];
```

Comment: Could you explain why your code works a little more in-depth?

Comment: on did load the if statements override to use different pics based on the device

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleOldImage:(UIImage *)orig toNewSize:(CGSize)finalSize {


CGSize origSize = orig.size;

CGFloat wScale = finalSize.width / origSize.width;
CGFloat hScale = finalSize.height / origSize.height;
CGFloat finalScale = (wScale > hScale) ? wScale : hScale;

CGRect finalRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, origSize.width * finalScale, origSize.height * finalScale );
finalRect.origin.x = ( finalSize.width - finalRect.size.width )/2;
finalRect.origin.y = ( finalSize.height - finalRect.size.height )/2;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( finalSize, YES, 0.0 );
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

[orig drawInRect:finalRect];
UIImage * finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return finalImage;
}
```